# Javascript adding values to radio buttons to input price

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a javascript block inside of a webpage im working on. I havent done javascript since highschool and it doesnt seem to want to come back to me :(

In this block of code i want to have 4 sets of radio buttons, each time a selection is picked, 
a price will be inputed to a variable for each radio group. i.e

```
    var firstPrice = $25
    var secondPrice = $56
    var thirdPrice = $80
    var fourthPrice = $90
```

then after each radio group has one selection there will be a function attached to the submit button that adds up each price to display the final amount inside of a hidden field

```
    var totalPrice = (firstPrice + secondPrice + thirdPrice + fourthPrice)
```

My question is, how do i attach a number value to a radio button within a group, same name but id is different in each group. Then do i just create a function that adds all the price groups up and then set the submit button to onClick = totalPrice();
Here is an example of one set of radio buttons:

```
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="model" value="radio" id="item_0" />
          item 1</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="model" value="radio" id="item_1" />
          item2</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="model" value="radio" id="item_2" />
          item3</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="model" value="radio" id="item_3" />
          Item4</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="model" value="radio" id="item_4" />
          item5</label>

          </form>
```

then my script looks something like:

```
    function finalPrice90{
var selectionFirst = document.modelGroup.value;
var selectionSecond = document.secondGroup.value;
var selectionThird = document.thirdGroup.value;
var selectionFourth = document.fourthGroup.Value;

var totalPrice = (selectionFirst + selectionSecond + selectionThird +         selectionFourth);
       }
```

Comment: If you use the submit button to update the price, then users will only see the updated price for a second or so until the page refreshes from from the submit. You likley want to update the price before they press submit (and make sure you re–calculate the price at the server).

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/ZLQXB/

Answer (score 0):

Set the `value` attribute of your radio inputs to the price each radio button should represent.

When it's time to calculate, simply loop through each group and get the `value` attribute if the checked radio.

Because the value attribute is a string representation of a number, you'll want to convert it back to a number before doing any math (but that's a simple `parseInt` or `parseFloat`).

Here's a working fiddle using pure JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/XxZwm/

A library like jQuery or Prototype (or MooTools, script.aculo.us, etc) may make this easier in the long run, depending on how much DOM manipulation code you don't want to re-invent a wheel for.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seem pretty simple, here's an example that should answer most questions. There is a single click listener on the form so whenever there is a click on a form control, the price will be updated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//function updatePrice(el) {
function updatePrice(event) {
  var el = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var form = el.form;
  if (!form) return;
  var control, controls = form.elements;
  var totalPrice = 0;
  var radios;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    if ((control.type == 'radio' || control.type == 'checkbox') && control.checked) {
      totalPrice += Number(control.value);
    }

    // Deal with other types of controls if necessary
  }
  form.totalPrice.value = '$' + totalPrice;
}

</script>

<form>
    <fieldset><legend>Model 1</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="model1" value="25">$25<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model1" value="35">$35<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model1" value="45">$45<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model1" value="55">$55<br>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Model 2</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="model2" value="1">$1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model2" value="2">$2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model2" value="3">$3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="model2" value="4">$4<br>
    <fieldset><legend>Include shipping?</legend>
      <span>$5</span><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="shipping"><br>
    </fieldset>

    <input name="totalPrice" readonly><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear form">
</form>
```

You could put a single listener on the form for click events and update the price automatically, in that case you can get rid of the update button.